# Is there any encoding problems?

Tags: c, stdio

I am trying to write these parameters in a file .txt, but when I open the file (even before that it shows me a warining about the encoding) it appers like a bug, full of ????, like this:

```
$�U�z�G��?xpto%�U\���(\�?xpto&�Uףp=
��?xpto'�UR���Q�?xpto(�U�������?xpto)�UH�z�G�?xpto*�U��(\���?xpto+�U>
ףp=�?xpto,�U���Q��?xpto-�U433333�?xpto
```

I've searched a lot about but as it is a specifically error, i cannot find nothing about it.
What is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct
{
    int age;
    double height;
    char name[64];
} Person;

void printPersonInfo(Person *p)
{
    printf("Person: %s, %d, %f\n", p->name, p->age, p->height);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int i;
    Person p = {35, 1.65, "xpto"};

    /* Validate number of arguments */
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("USAGE: %s fileName\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Open the file provided as argument */
    errno = 0;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Error opening file!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Write 10 itens on a file */
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {    
        p.age = p.age+1;
        p.height = p.height+0.03;
        fwrite(&p, sizeof(Person), 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you expect to find a text representation of your `Person`s in the destination file, you need to _define_ this text representation, and encode your (binary) `Person` objects into this representation.

Comment: You have [an urgent telephone call from your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on line 1. Your rubber duck wants to have a conversation with you where you can explain how you can `fwrite()` a 4 byte integer with value 7892879 into your file, end up writing this value in 4 bytes, then open the file and see this number in plain text, but taking up only four characters!

Answer (score 2):

The `fwrite` function is writing the binary representation of the struct `p` to the file.  If you want to write text, use `fprintf`:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d %f %s\n", p.age, p.height, p.name);
```